# How to pass class as a variable

Tags: c++

I have class Point, and i'm coding Circle. Then how to pass class as variable

```
int main() {
   Point p1(0, 0), p2(5, 8);
   Circle c1(p1, 4), c2(p2, 3);
   int sgd = c1.getIntersection(c2);
   cout<<"intersection: "<<sgd<<endl;
}
```

this is class Ponit

```
class Point {
  private: 
    int _x;
    int _y;
  public:
    Point() {
      _x = 0;
      _y = 0;
    }

    Point(int x, int y) {
      _x = x;
      _y = y;
      return Point(_x, _y);
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't pass a class, you pass an object of class type, which you seem to be doing when constructing `c1` and `c2`. However you haven't shown us the code for the `Circle` class so it's hard to tell if you got it right. Are you getting an error?

Comment: You pass it the same as any other parameter. Do you have an error? What does the `getIntersection` function look like? Constructors don't return values, so `return Point(_x, _y);` is incorrect and could also be causing an error. Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: "*Then how to pass class as variable*" It's not really clear what you mean. You can pass references or values to a function. A class is neither.

Comment: You can just build a instant object of that class, and then send as references(point& xx) / value(point xx) or pointer(point* xx).

Comment: You can't return anything from a constructor. (And how is the intersection of two circles an integer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for it:

```
class Point {
    public:
      int _x;
      int _y;
}
```

and in class Circle

```
Circle(Point x, int s);
```

Answer (score 1):

at this point the problem is located in the class circle,
you need to modify it so it can take a point as parameter:

```
class Circle
...public:

    Circle(const Point& P, int s);
```

after that you can pass objects/instances of the class point
like

```
Circle c1(p1, 4), c2(p2, 3);
```

this approach will require that the Circle class "knows" about a Point class, this is called dependencies since the Circle depends on the Point...

you can as work-around, define a Circle constructor with the 2 params too

```
Circle(int x, int y, int s);
```